# Delete from list on condition parent id and child id linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

```
{
  "companies":[
    {
      "CID":"1",
      "branches":[
        {
          "BID":"1",
          "stores":[
            {
              "SID":"2",
              "departments":[
                {
                  "DID":2
                },
                {
                  "DID":3
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CID":"2",
      "branches":[
        {
          "BID":"1",
          "stores":[
            {
              "SID":"2",
              "departments":[
                {
                  "DID":2
                },
                {
                  "DID":3
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete data from list where  CID=2 and BID=1and SID=2.with basis of these three condition data should be delete

```
userEnitityDetails.companies
    .RemoveAll(C => C.branches
        .Any(B => B.stores
            .Any(S=> S.SID.Equals(InputStoreName))));
```

Comment: IMHO you better show the result you want before and after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a possibility of the `companies` object or the nested objects to be null, then use:

```
companies?.RemoveAll(c => 
    c.CId == 2 && (c.Branches?.Any(b => 
        b.BId == 1 && (b.Stores?.Any(s => s.SId == 2)??false))??false));
```

Answer (score 0):

You code does not test IDs except SID.

I guess you want to do that ?

```
            Companies
            .RemoveAll(c => c.CID == 2 && c.Branchs
                .Any(b => b.BID == 1 && b.Stores
                    .Any(s => s.SID == 2)));
```

Comment: no its giving error  System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'